# How to avoid leaks when paging in a RESTful web service?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, restful-architecture

We have a RESTful web service that returns a collection of tickets. Because it's possible for the collection returned to be too large to be processed in a single gulp, we've added *offset* and *limit* query parameters. The idea is that we run the query, then skip the first *offset* records, then return the next *limit* records.

The problem is that this can leak tickets.

Suppose, for example, that there are eight tickets that need work, at the time the client first queries:

```
ID STATUS
00 needs work
01 needs work
02 needs work
03 needs work
04 needs work
05 needs work
06 needs work
07 needs work
```

If the client requests the tickets that need work, with an *offset* of 0 and a *limit* of 4, we'll return:

```
ID STATUS
00 needs work
01 needs work
02 needs work
03 needs work
```

If someone else, then does some work, changing some tickets to:

```
01 doesn't need work
02 doesn't need work
```

If the client then requests the tickets that need work, with an *offset* of 4 and a *limit* of 4, the results of the query will be:

```
ID STATUS
00 needs work
03 needs work
04 needs work
05 needs work
06 needs work
07 needs work
```

And after we skip the first four records, we'll return:

```
06 needs work
07 needs work
```

And tickets 04 and 05 will have been skipped.

If we go back to the ticket table on every subsequent paging request, we'll leak tickets, if tickets on earlier pages have been changed so that they fall out of the query results.

Part of me is wondering how important this is.

The client is going to request the *needs work* tickets on some sort of schedule. When there are more tickets than the limit, it will then page through the rest in multiple calls, incrementing *offset* on each call. If we do nothing, we will sometimes leak *needs work* tickets, but they will be picked up the next time the client requests new *needs work* tickets.

That is, the leaked tickets will only be leaked on this pass, they'll show up on the next.

But if it is important that we not leak tickets, I don't see any way of resolving it other than saving the identifiers of all of the *needs work* tickets during the first call, and then paging through the collection of identifiers, rather than through the tickets themselves.

We could, for example, when the client requests *needs work* tickets with an offset of zero, populate a second table with the ids of all of the tickets that need work, then return the first *limit* tickets that are in the second table. The next call, we use *offset* and *limit* against the second table, to determine which tickets to return.

The problem with this is we need to deal with multiple clients running simultaneously. So we need a primary key on the second table that we can match against a specific client, based on what is in the request.

I'd like to be able to manage this without putting additional burden on the client programmers. But I don't see how.

**Is there any way for me to tell, by examining a request and its headers, that it came from the same client as an earlier request? I've not been able to find one.**

We're currently returning paging information in the response headers:

```
Paging-offset: 0
Paging-limit: 4
Paging-returnedCount: 4
Paging-totalRecordCount: 54
```

What I'm thinking is that we might return a *Paging-collection* value, when we're paging, which would provide a key value into the second table. We could then require the client to provide the collection value when they make a request with *offset* != 0.

Does this seem reasonable? Do you think that this would put too great a burden on the client programmers?

How have other people solved this problem? Or do they just ignore it?

Comment: You should probably use a `from` instead of `skip`. The second request would be `/tickets?limit=4&from=3` where `from` is the starting point of the list. This, of course, works only in a world where your tickets are well ordered (which seems to be the case with the ticket ID). Returning a "next link" for the consumer of the api to call to get the following pages would also be a good idea.

Comment: I did not read the full question, but I have the impression, that you should version your tickets, e.g. with etags or with if-modified-since. I guess the problem is that you change the collection while reading its pages. I think this is more like a common pagination problem and not a REST related problem.

Comment: If you turn the "from" suggestion into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way for me to tell, by examining a request and its headers, that it came from the same client as an earlier request? I've not been able to find one.

You're not supposed to be able to - stateless protocol.  In particular, if you are trying to do REST, you want the request to have all of the necessary information so that a new server can answer the request when the original server is busy.

But possibilities include giving each client its own resource to work with.  There are a number of different ways you can match the request to the unique resource.

> The problem with this is we need to deal with multiple clients running simultaneously.

As a rule, REST works much better if you can provide multiple clients with a common understanding of resources, rather than trying to tailor your representations to each.

Consider: Alice queries for a pile of work, Bob changes something, then Charlie queries for a pile of work.  Can you live with it if Charlie gets a representation of the pile that was cached by Alice's query (ie, before Bob's change)?  Cuz that's kind of how the web is designed to work....

(It doesn't have to - you can have each response set a bunch of no-cache headers.  But it's something you should be thinking about, because it may be trying to tell you that the REST architectural constraints are not a great fit for your problem.)

> How have other people solved this problem? Or do they just ignore it?

Well, it's a concurrent modification that's invalidating your iterator, right?  Maybe you just pitch a fit and force the client to start over....

You might look into [AtomSyndication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287), and how some services [use it](http://docs.geteventstore.com/http-api/3.0.3/reading-streams/)

For your case, I'd probably look at turning the problem around; instead of asking the server for N tickets that have some property, I'd look into asking the server for all tickets in some range that have the property.  The client can just keep navigating through ranges until it fills its own bucket.

Another way of describing your problem is that you are trying to page through a mutable collection.

If you drop the paging constraint -- each request always fetches N unworked tickets starting from the first one, that's pretty straight forward.

If you drop the mutable constraint -- paging through an immutable list is straight forward.  Making a mutable list immutable may be easy -- instead of asking for the latest version of the list, you ask for the version of the list as of some particular point in time.  This is a very happy problem to have when using event sourcing.

> One thing we've discussed is having one query return a list of ticket IDs, which would be small enough to return all of them, all of the time, then have a second query to return a single ticket given a query.

Another good answer; that's fundamentally the way web pages work -- (relatively) small payload of html, with hyperlinks to the java script, media, and so on that extends the representation.

Comment: One thing we've discussed is having one query return a list of ticket IDs, which would be small enough to return all of them, all of the time, then have a second query to return a single ticket given a query.